# NS_ENUM errors when building app using Apportable

Tags: android, ios, enums, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

I have used several NS_ENUM's in my Cocos2d-Iphone app which I am porting to Android using Apportable. The app works perfectly in Xcode but I get several errors with the NS_ENUM's when building using Apportable. Below are some of the errors:

```
/Users/mac/Documents/BallTestApp/BallManager.mm:57:32: error: assigning to 'ballTypes' from incompatible type 'int'
    lastCreatedBallType = NULL;
                        ^ ~~~~
/Users/mac/Documents/BallTestApp/BallManager.mm:382:66: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'ballTypes' with an lvalue of type 'int'
                                     withBallType:pBallType atLocation:ballPosition withManager:self];
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/mac/Documents/BallTestApp/Ball.h:193:103: note: passing argument to parameter 'myType' here
-(id)initBallWithWorld:(b2World*)world inLayer:(GamePlayLayer*)layer withBallType:(ballTypes)myType atLocation:(CGPoint)myLocation withManager:(BallManager*)myBallManager;
                                                                                             ^
/Users/mac/Documents/BallTestApp/BallManager.mm:575:79: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'xBallDistances' with an lvalue of type 'int'
    myBallPos = self.carlBall.position.x  + [self getBallDistance:i];
                                                                  ^
```

I defined ballTypes as:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ballTypes)  {

redBall = 0, 
yellowBall = 1,
blueBall = 2,
greenBall = 3
};
```

I also defined my other enum's in a similar way.

Comment: You will get the same errors if you enable the recommended compiler warnings in xcode. Simply cast the values, and use 0 or better the actual enum name,  not NULL (reserved for pointer types). Example: type = (ballTypes)redBall.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is defined like so:

```
 #define NULL 0
```

Therefore you're trying to assign int 0 to an enum value.

Using `= redBall` instead of `= NULL` will solve the warning.